# while assigning the path in python for openssl in python is not working

Tags: python, openssl, rsa, pyopenssl

```py
p12_name = G72XN87TV
print(repositoryPath+ios_team_id)
cert_path1 = str(home + "/Documents/Automator/repository/"+ios_team_id+"/certs/distribution/"+p12_name+".cer")
print(cert_path1)
cert_path = '\"'+cert_path1+'\"'
print(cert_path)
        
cert_der = "\"" + "cert.der" + "\""
#encrypting the provisioning profiles and p12
print("\n\nopenssl", "aes-256-cbc", "-k", "vajr", "-in", cert_path, "-out", cert_der, "-a", "-d\n")
```

```
> output
openssl aes-256-cbc -k vajr -in "/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/repository/G72XN87TV/certs/distribution/3JGNP8TN9X.cer" -out "cert.der" -a -d
"/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/repository/G72XN87TV/certs/distribution/3JGNP8TN9X.cer": No such file or directory
4624252524:error:02FFF002:system library:func(4095):No such file or directory:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:255:fopen('"/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/repository/G72XN87TV/certs/distribution/3JGNP8TN9X.cer"', 'r')
4624252524:error:20FFF002:BIO routines:CRYPTO_internal:system lib:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:257:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/automation/mew2.py", line 200, in <module>
    IOS(app_id, config_data, ios_project_folder, tobechanged_path, version_name, version_code, demo)
  File "/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/automation/IosFiles/ios.py", line 68, in __init__
    AutomateBuild(app_id, config_data, ios_project_folder)
  File "/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/automation/IosFiles/automateBuild.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.automate_build()
  File "/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/automation/IosFiles/automateBuild.py", line 117, in automate_build
    print(subprocess.check_output(["openssl", "aes-256-cbc", "-k", "vajr", "-in", cert_path, "-out", "cert.der", "-a", "-d"],cwd=repositoryPath+ios_team_id))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['openssl', 'aes-256-cbc', '-k', 'vajr', '-in', '"/Users/machd/Documents/Automator/repository/G72XN87TV/certs/distribution/3JGNP8TN9X.cer"', '-out', 'cert.der', '-a', '-d']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I used the code to generate the der file but the path which is passed in the variable is not considered it's not working. While giving that command in the terminal it's working but in code it's not considering it as a path

Comment: Please post your code [not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please use the code tags to paste your code in your question.

Comment: I have changed according to your comment. @flaxel – flaxel